How can I adjust the number of candidates shown in ibus for Chinese input on Ubuntu?
I am using ibus for Chinese input on Ubuntu, but I am unable to find an option to adjust the number of candidates displayed in the candidate window.

I have checked through dconf-editor but didn't find any relevant setting under /desktop/ibus/panel.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

I looked through the settings in dconf-editor under ibus -> panel.
I explored the GUI preferences for ibus and the input method, but I couldn't find a way to adjust the candidate count.

I’m looking for a way to either increase or decrease the number of candidate words displayed in the candidate window.
System Information:

Ubuntu version: [22.04]
ibus version: [1.5.26]
Input Method: [rime]


I finally found a solution.
First of all, I was confused with ibus and ibus-rime. While there exists some inputs directly based on ibus, rime is also a popular Chinese input framework.
The dependency graph is as follows (mermaid):
flowchart TD
    Uos[Ubuntu] -->|calls| Fcitx(fcitx)
    Uos[Ubuntu] -->|calls| Ibs(ibus)
    Ibs -->|calls| Pin[ibus-libpinyin]
    Ibs -->|calls| Anthy[ibus-anthy]
    Ibs -->|calls| Oth["(Other ibus input methods...)"]
    Ibs -->|calls| Rime("ibus-rime (A framework)")
    Rime -->|calls| Luna[rime-data-luna-pinyin]
    Rime -->|calls| Cangjie[rime-data-cangjie]
    Rime -->|calls| Ice[iDevel/rime-ice]


For setting up rime inputs, simply edit the file: ~/.config/ibus/rime/default.yaml.
For other ibus inputs, simply set it up in it's settings. (Right click the ibus menu and click Preferences)
